# Same session in multiple tabs and when a user logs in any tab and if they navigate in a new tab of same browser they must already be logged in

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know how to get same session multiple tabs and clear the session when all tabs are gone.Then,

- When a user logs into the site in any tab and if they navigate to the site in a new tab they must already be logged in in the same browser.
- When a user logs out of any tab they must log out of all tabs immediately.
- A user can refresh the page and stay logged in. 
  -Once all tabs are closed the user is logged out and must log back in.

Here,i set and get the sessionStorage in Utils,

```
let getSessionStorage = (key) => {
 return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
};
let setSessionStorage = (key, value) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
};
```

Here is my code after getting login success, i set the sessionStorage data,

```
if (this.props.isLoginSuccess) 
{
      Utils.setSessionStorage('clu_email', this.props.userData.clu_email);
      Utils.setSessionStorage('cli_name', this.props.userData.cli_name);
      Utils.setSessionStorage('clu_id', this.props.userData.usr_id);
      Utils.setSessionStorage('clu_idv', this.props.userData.clu_idv);
      Utils.setSessionStorage('clu_name', this.props.userData.clu_name);
      Utils.setSessionStorage('clu_type', this.props.userData.clu_type);
      Utils.setSessionStorage('clu_cat', this.props.userData.clu_cat);
      Utils.setSessionStorage('cli_depart', this.props.userData.cli_department);
      Utils.setSessionStorage('cli_logo_image', this.props.userData.cli_logo_image);
      Utils.setSessionStorage('usr_id', this.props.userData.usr_id);
      if (this.props.userData.clu_type == 1){
      this.props.history.push('fmp/dashboard');
      } 
      else 
      {
        Utils.setSessionStorage('org_id', this.props.userData.cli_id);
        Utils.setSessionStorage('cli_name', this.props.userData.cli_name);
        Utils.setSessionStorage('cli_logo_image', this.props.userData.cli_logo_image);
        this.props.history.push('client/dashboard');
       }
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
```

Here,i get the session data and check if its is true it navigate to dashboard else it navigates to login,

```
<Route path="/fmp/dashboard" render={props => (
                     Utils.getSessionStorage('clu_id')
                        ? <FMPDashboard {...props} />
                        : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login'}} />
                )} />
```

Comment: `sessionStorage` is connected only to one tab. You need `localStorage` here.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is about your method that is not working? (Also, tip: try storing the users session in ephemeral cookies and using express's session management)

Comment: When a user logs out of any tab they must log out of all tabs immediately in this case if i use local storage i cant handle it. is there any other method to do it? @ritaj

Comment: When a user logs into the site in any tab and if they navigate to the site in a new tab they must already be logged in in the same browser. I could not able to manage this, if i use session data i get data in all tabs but i could able to redirect to previous tab logged in page, it again redirects to login main page. @–Sydney Y

Answer (score 0):

You can save the key in `localStorage` instead of the `sessionStorage` and detect if the storage changed like this:

```
window.addEventListener("storage", function () {
  // Check if the key changed and is empty
  // Do your logout logic
}, false);
```

Keep in mind the event will be raised in all the tabs/windows OTHER than the one that triggered the change, so you will have to manually log out of the windows that changed the storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
const newTab = window.open('https://example.com', '_blank');
```

Comment: please add some more details, code-only answer are not of high-quality. How does it solve the problem?